# Do Spatial Graphs (3-Dimensional Graphs) Exist?

Tags: graph, spatial, computational-geometry, computer-science-theory

In the university, I just learnt flat graphs (2-dimensional graphs). So, I was wondering if it is possible to exist spatial graphs (3-dimensional graphs).

Answer (score 1):

Graphs are abstract data structures with edges and vertices, the nature of which is unspecified and not necessarily embedded in some geometric space. For instance, a family tree is a abstract graph.

Of course a natural representation is on a sheet of paper, hence embedded in 2D space. But 3D is also possible.

In particular, the edges and vertices of a polyhedron do form a graph embedded in 3D space.